# Issue when appending object from another file.

Tags: game-engine, append

I am trying to append the sky object from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11542084/water_0.99_optimized.blend) (warning clicking this will directly download the blend file). It is a BGE scene that I got from [this](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?242940-unlimited-planar-reflections-amp-refraction-update) post detailing Martin's work on an ocean shader.

Immediately after appending the object though one can notice that it does not look similar to how it is in the original file.

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have BGE set as current rendering engine in the current file?

Comment: Also,if I recognize it correctly the file you are trying to append from is one those realistic real time water demos from Martinsh. If I recall correctly those were some pretty complex files with lots of custom shaders and filters and some scripts and interconnecting parts working together. Removing a single object from context will likely break stuff, and things are probably not gonna work correctly on their own.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I have the Game Engine selected and also used Texture for the viewport. I also tried appending everything that is inside the objects folder. Everything then looks fine except from the sky. I thought everything is indeed located inside that folder.

Comment: I haven't thoroughly inspected the file but there may be extra python scripts in the text editor that don't get imported from the objects alone. Not sure though